# Eclipse and NetBeans PHP Xdebug session never completes

Tags: php, eclipse, netbeans, xdebug

I am using UniServer Zero XIII with PHP 7.1. From the phpinfo.php file, I can see that xdebug enabled:

[image]

When I try to debug the source code and use a breakpoint on NetBeans, the XDebug session never completed:

[image]

When I go to see the execution of the web application from the web browser, it keeps trying to load the page, but it never completes.

I experience the same on Eclipse:

[image]

I am trying to understand why the Xdebug session never completes, and what I need to do to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: have you eresed you .metadata folder?

Comment: Yes, I went to C:\Users\[username]\workspace\.metadata and removed the entire .metadata folder. The problem remains exactly the same, so removing the .metadata folder was not the solution for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran out of time to find a solution to this problem. Unfortunately, I only received one answer to this question, and it did not solve my problem. I had to purchase a Zend Studio Perpetual license for Zend Studio 13.6, and now I can use breakpoints, debug my code using Zend Debugger (the competitor of XDebug), and everything works correctly.

I tried as much as I could to fix the problem I experienced with XDebug on both NetBeans and Eclipse, but I ran out of time and I needed to move on. I had to pay $89 for my Zend Studio Perpetual license, which includes free upgrades for one year. I wanted to save money by using Eclipse or NetBeans, but this XDebug issue forced me to move from an open source to a proprietary solution in this case.

Edited on August 29th, 2017:

I finally have XDebug working on Zend Studio. I could not quickly configure Zend Debugger on UniServer Zero XIII, so I did the modifications that I am showing below, to the following file: C:[my path]\UniformServer13_3_2_ZeroXIII\UniServerZ\core\php71\php_production.ini:

```
[xdebug]
#zend_extension=${US_ROOTF}/core/php71/extensions/php_xdebug.dll
zend_extension="C:\[my path]\UniformServer13_3_2_ZeroXIII\UniServerZ\core\php71\extensions\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
#xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey=default
```

I changed the port from 9000 to 9001, and used an absolute path with double quotes to the zend_extension to specify where the php_xdebug.dll extension is located. I am not sure if this last step made any difference, or if only changing the port from 9000 to 9001 and then restarting Apache. But at least now I can configure breakpoints to stop the program there and see the values of variables I want to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe found the solution, the problem was that you deleted the metadata:

When a project (including the source roots) is deleted or moved outside of NetBeans and while NetBeans are closed, then after NetBeans are started again, line breakpoints belonging to sources which do not exist any more are deleted.

Therefore, IMHO, in your case either some exceptions were thrown, which interrupted the breakpoints elimination and which would be in your messages.log file, or you've deleted just the project metadata without the sources.

And this is the only case in which I'm able to reproduce your issue:

1) Create a Servlet2Stateless sample project (or any Java project should work
   this way IMHO)

2) Right-click on the project in Projects window and select Copy...

3) Press Copy button

4) Open Servlet2Stateless.java file from the copied project
   (Servlet2Stateless_1)

5) Submit breakpoint to line 72

6) Debug the Servlet2Stateless_1 project, after it suspends on the
   breakpoint, press continue and finish the debugger session.

7) Delete your proyect_1 project, but be sure not to check on
   "Also delete sources under..."

8) Debug the original project

9) You get en error message
   "Not able to submit breakpoint LineBreakpoint Servlet2Stateless.java:72,
    reason: No source root found for URL
   'file:/tmp/NetBeansProjects/ServletStateless_1/src/java/servlet/stateless/
    Servlet2Stateless.java'. Verify the setup of project sources."

10) This message is harmless, but if you want to get rid of is, it's easy
    to click on "Invalid LineBreakpoint Servlet2Stateless.java : 72" line,
    which opens the source file and remove the breakpoint.

Since there is nothing severe in this issue, I'm reducing the priority to P3.
We can think about fixing this by ignoring breakpoints that belong to source roots without a corresponding project and not being added as an extra source root in the Sources window.

Check the whole info [here](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=227076)

Comment: I was experiencing this problem before I deleted the .metadata folder, so I think it has nothing to do with my action of deleting the .metadata folder. I do not think it is the cause of the problem nor the solution, but I may be wrong. I guess it is something else.